# Memory Friendly Fast Key-Value Access Solution for Android

Tags: java, android, database, memory, dictionary

I have an Android application that iterates through an array of thousands of integers and it uses them as key values to access pairs of integers (let us call them id's) in order to make calculations with them. It needs to do it as fast as possible and in the end, it returns a result which is crucial to the application.

I tried loading a HashMap into the memory for fast access to those numbers but it resulted in OOM Exception. I also tried writing those id's to a RandomAccessFile and storing their offsets on the file to another HashMap but it was way too slow. Also, the new HashMap that only stores the offsets is still occupying a large memory.

Now I am considering SQLite but I am not sure if it will be any faster. Are there any structures or libraries that could help me with that?

EDIT: Number of keys are more than 20 million whereas I only need to access thousands of them. I do not know which ones I will access beforehand because it changes with user input.

Comment: thousands of integers cant take so much memory, u must be doing something wrong...

Comment: how did u save the keys and where in the first place? Id suggest to somehow save em in a sorted way, and have files to be bucket of values of the range suited keys...

Comment: The keys are saved to a HashMap and then serialized in an administrative console. Later, in the Android application, they are deserialized back into a HashMap. So I have the chance to modify how these keys are stored but I cannot change the way they are used as keys in my algorithm.

I did not understand the advantage of sorting them though.

Comment: There is no simple solution for this where your app require a specific amount of memory, but your deployment platform is not allowing you to use what's required.

Comment: check my answer to understand why buckets can be helpfull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Trove's [`TIntLongHashMap`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TIntLongHashMap.html) to map primitive `int`s to primitive `long`s (which store the `int`s of your value pair). This saves you the object overhead of a plain vanilla `Map`, which forces you to use wrapper types.

**EDIT**

Since your update states you have more than 20 million mappings, there will likely be more space-efficient structures than a hash map.  An approach to partition your keys into buckets, combined with some sub-key compression will likely save you half the memory over even the most efficient hash map implementation.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I concatenate the two integers into a long and store them like that?

Comment: @babatenor Yes, if your goal is to conserve memory.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, though it is unknown how many digits each integer in the pair will have during run-time. So it will be a problem to split them back to individual integers again.

Similar to your idea, I tried storing the pair as a single String with a delimiter to separate two integers but it holds almost as much memory to store a string than two integers.

Comment: Since you said *integer*, I assumed you meant a 32-bit `int` type. What is the maximum range of the values in the pair?

Comment: Oh, now I get your point. You suggest bit-wise concatenation. I never thought about it. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by sub-key compression?

Comment: Let's say your bucket size is 65536 (2^16). You don't need to store each 32-bit key value in this bucket, but only the lower 16 bits, saving you 2 bytes per entry. Or, you could store the keys as offsets to each other. If the next value is +4 from the current, you can encode that information in 2 bits, plus the marker overhead. Also, if your value pairs are primarily low values that won't take up a full 32 bits, you can compress these values to take up less space.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is an embedded relational database, which uses indexes. I would bet it is much faster than using RandomAccessFile. You can give it a try.

Comment: But nothing beats an in-memory data structure for speed, which appears the OP's central goal.

Comment: I was thinking about adding each key as a column and storing the integers under these columns. Then I can query these columns and obtain the pairs. Do you think it will be a fast approach?

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable approach. Try it, if it is fast enough, it will certainly be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to rearrange the keys in Buckets - what i mean is identify (more or less) the distribution of your keys, then make files that corresponds to each range of keys (the point is that every file must contain just as much integers that can get in memory and no more then that) then when you search for a key, you just read the whole file to the memory and look for it.

exemple, assuming the distribution of the key is uniform, store 500k values corresponding to the 0-500k key values, 500k values corresponding to 500k-1mil keys and so on...

**EDIT :** if you did try this approach, and it still went slow, i still have some tricks in my sleaves:

1. First make sure that your division is actually close to equal between all the buckets.
2. Try to make the buckets smaller, by making more buckets.
3. The idea about correct division to buckets by ranges is that when you search for a key, you go to the corresponding range bucket and The key either in it or that it is not in the whole collection. so there is no point on Concurnetly reading another bucket.
4. I never done that, cause im not sure concurrency works on I\O's, but it may be helpfull to Read the whole file with 2 threads one from top to bottom and the other from bottom to top until they meet. (or something like that)
5. While you read the whole bucket into memory, split it to 3-4 arraylists, Run 3-4 working threads to search your key on each of the arrays, the search must end way faster then.

Comment: I also tried this approach. I created 10 separate hashmaps that store only keys within a certain range. However, when I was doing the search on application side, even though loading the hashmap into memory was successful, there was a considerable increase in time required to obtain the final result due to inefficiency of having to load every hash-map one by one.

Comment: Have you tried using Concurrency? you will be able to search faster this way... also, maybe you should split the keys to more files.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the term. Could you please explain it a little bit more?

What I understand is to use multiple threads to access separate buckets at the same time, is it right?

Comment: you wont be able to do exactly that - I dont know if it has the same effect as it has running on the memory. anyway ill edit my answer.

Comment: Multiple threads won't give you a performance boost if all of them are IO-bound. Keep in mind also, most Android devices use single-core processors, so they won't benefit from concurrency at all.